# How to get cartesian coordinates about element inside of ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Having a ColumnLayout that have inside 4 different items, positioned using Layout, how can I get cartesian coordinates from one of those item?

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ColumnLayout {
    spacing: 0
    Layout.topMargin: 10
    Layout.bottomMargin: 10

    Image {
        id: item1 
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        sourceSize: Qt.size(204, 96)
    }

    Text {
        id: item2
        Layout.topMargin: 15
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        text: "hello"

    }

    Text {
        id: item3
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        text: "world"
    }
}
```

What is the position based in cartesian coordinates of element with id "item3"? How to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain the position of the item3 with respect to the ColumnLayout you must use the properties [x](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#x-prop), [y](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#y-prop):

```
// ...

Text {
    id: item3
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    text: "world"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(x, y)
}
```

If you want respect to the screen you must use the [mapToGlobal()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method) function:

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log(mapToGlobal(x, y))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it but it returns (0,0) that isn't the right position in my application. I want to know relative position in my application.

Comment: @jgd So I suspect that you are implementing the solution incorrectly so if you want help you should provide an MCVE

Comment: I just tried to get x,y properties without mapToGlobal(). Using mapToGlobal() function. It solves the issue. Thanks again.